# How to handle hapi validation errors?

Tags: node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I have following route code for hapi...

---

```
const routeConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/user',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
        firstName: Joi.string().required(),
      }
    },
    handler
  }
}
```

So when I don't pass the `firstName` it throws error like this

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "child \"firstName\" fails because [\"firstName\" is required]",
    "validation": {
        "source": "payload",
        "keys": [
            "firstName"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I need to handle the above error in catch

```
const handler = async(request, reply) => {
  try {
    const payload = request.payload
    const createUser = await User.create(payload)
    let token = Helpers.createJwt(createUser) 
    reply({ success: true, message: 'User created successFully', token })
  } catch(err) {
     // need to do something here to handle the error like
     if (err) {
       reply ({ error: "firstName is required", message: "Signup unsuccessfull" })
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much better solution:

```
config: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                firstName: Joi.string().required(),
            },
            failAction(request, reply, source, error) {
              reply({
                error: 'badRequest',
              }).code(400);
            },
        },
    },
```

If the Joi validation fails, it will trigger the failAction and you will be able to handle the error (sending it to log service and/or return a specific message).

It's a bit hidden in the doc but here is [the relevant part](https://hapijs.com/api#-routeoptionspayloadfailaction)

I must confess, I did'nt tried it with hapi 17...

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Your right... And the documentation is not really clear on this point

Comment: Hi ernest... I have a question... when I start my hapi server then doesn't show any logs... Do you have any idea about it? If you know the answer then I will raise  a question for it

Comment: Yes I have the answer. Check the "creating a server" section here https://hapijs.com/tutorials. For hapi version below 17, you should put a console.log in the server.start callback

Comment: Do you mean this `options: {
            prettyPrint: false,
            logEvents: ['response']
        }`??

Comment: That's if you want to use hapi-pino plugin (never heard of it)... Easiest solution is `const init = async () => {

    await server.start();
    console.log('Server running at: ${server.info.uri}');
};`

Comment: Hi Ernest Can we use [helmet npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) in hapi framework?

Comment: Never heard of helmet… Quick search => https://helmetjs.github.io/see-also/
It seems that something name blankie is recommended (https://github.com/nlf/blankie)

Comment: Hi Ernest do you have answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516579/add-prefix-to-all-apis-in-hapi

Comment: Hi Ernest do you know how to deploy hapi code on aws lambda. Kindly reply

Comment: Hi Anthony. 

I've worked a bit on serverless options for hapi. The biggest issue I had is based on routing (because, you don't have a server to handle it anymore)

Concerning Lambda, I have worked a little bit with that. My advice is to go directly with the serverless framework and remove Hapi from your code.

(Here is rapid video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUTGk64jppM&list=PLzvRQMJ9HDiT5b4OsmIBiMbsPjfp4kfg3&index=1)

If you can't maybe Google app engine is better because it will run your hapi code directly and you have serverless benefits (payment for consumption and scaling)

Comment: At the end of me trying to make Hapi running on Lambda I found a article explaining how to keep routing in Hapi and passing by the AWS API Gateway but I can't find it anymore but it exists somewhere on the web

Comment: Hi Ernest I have a question. Can you please help?

Comment: Maybe, fire up !

Comment: Cool... I need to integrate Sentry in my hapi server So I need common file from where all the request passes in hapi server. So whenever I get any failure I will use Sentry over there. Overall I need common handler for all the files. Is it possible? By the way do you have any app installed you are lightning fast

Comment: I have an app installed.
First of all, I didn't installed sentry on our servers but it is there. So, for what I can see, fatal errors are automatically catch.

We also create a module that format errors to our need and send them through `raven.captureException`. It is used for not fatal errors. In this module, you will want to pass the request in order to debug. Can't help you much more. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Earnest could you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182275/how-to-register-hapi-cron-with-the-latest-version-of-hapi-js)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try with something like this ?

```
const routeConfig = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/user',
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
        firstName: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('firstName is required')),
      }
    },
    handler
  }
}
```

Take a look on this page [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyerrorerr)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Sparw... is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way to do that properly.. :/

Comment: your answer helps me to change the message and  Ernest's answer helps me to return that messsage... So thanks it works...